# What preposition should I use here: "written of me" or "written about me"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> ... having reviews and articles **written of me** in The New York Press.

or

> ... having reviews and articles **written about me** in The New York Press.

Comment: _Featuring_ perhaps?

Comment: Featuring is good, but has its own implications. This is also a fragment in a long list of fragments: "About my life: settling in New York, opening my ..., exhibiting..., having reviews written ...", so simple is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend *about*. In this context *of* is incorrect, and cannot be used with the meaning that you indend. The word *on* is possible, but in this context the word *on* could be misinterpreted, and doesn't flow as naturally as *about*.

Comment: +1 And I find it interesting that the OP uses "about" in the title anyway. ^_^

Comment: Thank you thank you!<br> Later in the ms the writer says <br>A journalist wrote of me "...blah ..."<br> which seems correct

Comment: @Bobbi: yes, to "write something of someone" is idiomatic, to "write of someone" less so.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with *about*.

But the only one that doesn't make much sense is *of*.